# View the history of SingleEmailMessage usage

Tags: apex, rest-api, email, limits, singleemailmessage

I know how to see how many SingleEmailMessages we've sent in the current GMT day, but I need to know if it's possible to see a history of emails further back than that. For example, **for the past week, I need to know how many SingleEmailMessages were sent each day**. Can this be done?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For emails sent < 30 days ago, there's a log: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you @identigral. I looked into that and the log looks a little too complicated to help me very much. I ended up just writing a schedulable apex class that uses something similar to this:

List<System.OrgLimit> limits = OrgLimits.getAll();

for (System.OrgLimit aLimit : limits) {
    if(aLimit.getName()=='SingleEmail'){
        /*
        Send email to myself with body = 
            'Limit Name: ' + aLimit.getName() + '<br/>' +
            'Limit Value: ' + aLimit.getLimit() + '<br/>' +
            'Usage Value: ' + aLimit.getValue()
        */
    }   
}